How can a term for a moral concept be "used as a shorthand for one or more concepts which do have a legal meaning"?
Aren't the sentences in bold contradictory? If "There is no legal concept of ownership", then how can Ownership be "used as a shorthand for one or more concepts which do have a legal meaning"?
If Ownership is solely a moral concept, then any use of Ownership (including for shorthand) shall necessarily refer to moral concepts.

1.4.3 ESTATES IN LAND
A second aspect to the land law logic which must be internalised, and which again is difficult (partly due to terminology), is the idea of estates in land rather than ownership of land. To understand land law it is essential to get rid of the idea of ownership of land. There is no such thing as ‘the owner’ of a piece of land in English and Welsh land law. This does not mean that people are lying when they say they own their land, nor does it mean they are being inaccurate as such. This book will refer to landowners and owners of land. It is not that this term is wrong, it is that is [sic] has no legal definition. There is no legal concept of ownership, although of course there is a moral concept, and indeed the term is used as a shorthand for one or more concepts which do have a legal meaning [emphasis added]—such as freeholder, leaseholder, owner of the freehold title, and registered proprietor. To a certain extent, all of these terms means ‘owner’, although not ‘the owner’.

Emma Lees, The Principles of Land Law (Oxford University Press, 2020), page 20.

Even scientists routinely use vague intuitive terms to explain the gist of their reasoning as stand-ins for more opaque technical terms, and as shorthands that are technically incorrect. This is called "abuse of notation". "If X is solely a moral concept, then any use of X (including for shorthand) shall necessarily refer to moral concepts" is simply false, that is not how language works. Just because the core meaning of X belongs to some field does not mean X cannot be used as a stand-in for (multiple) concepts it motivates outside of it.
